# Problem with apache arrow: error C2668: 'arrow::internal::launder': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg, apache-arrow

I started to use Apache arrow. I installed it via vcpkg.
Everything was ok until I updated the installed arrow to 6.0.1.
I installed it using following command from powershell console:

```
vcpkg install arrow:x64-windows-static
```

It was installed successfully and I saw the success message (somehow):

```
The package arrow provides CMake targets:
        find_package(arrow CONFIG REQUIRED)
        target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE re2::re2 arrow_static parquet_static arrow_bundled_dependencies)
```

I have a file named `csv_column_test.cpp`. Then I commented out all contents of that file, except these two lines:

```
#define ARROW_STATIC
#include <arrow/api.h>
```

and tried to compile it. I continuously encounter this error:

```
error C2668: 'arrow::internal::launder': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

What I do miss?
How to make things working again?

Thanks.

Here is the complete error log:

```
>------ Build All started: Project: StockPredII, Configuration: x64-Debug (default) ------
  [1/2] Building CXX object splib\CMakeFiles\splib_test.dir\sparrow\csv_column_test.cpp.obj
  FAILED: splib/CMakeFiles/splib_test.dir/sparrow/csv_column_test.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE=VCPKG -D_SILENCE_CXX17_RESULT_OF_DEPRECATION_WARNING -I\Catch2\include -I..\..\..\splib -IE:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fosplib\CMakeFiles\splib_test.dir\sparrow\csv_column_test.cpp.obj /Fdsplib\CMakeFiles\splib_test.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\..\splib\sparrow\csv_column_test.cpp
E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow\util\aligned_storage.h(36): error C2668: 'arrow::internal::launder': ambiguous call to overloaded function
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/util/launder.h(29): note: could be 'T *arrow::internal::launder<T>(T *) noexcept'
          with
          [
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\new(33): note: or       '_Ty *std::launder<T>(_Ty *) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>,
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/util/aligned_storage.h(36): note: while trying to match the argument list '(T *)'
          with
          [
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/util/aligned_storage.h(36): note: while compiling class template member function 'T *arrow::internal::AlignedStorage<T>::get(void) noexcept'
          with
          [
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/result.h(431): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T *arrow::internal::AlignedStorage<T>::get(void) noexcept' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/result.h(435): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'arrow::internal::AlignedStorage<T>' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>
          ]
  E:\sandbox\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\arrow/buffer_builder.h(156): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'arrow::Result<std::unique_ptr<arrow::Buffer,std::default_delete<arrow::Buffer>>>' being compiled
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

By the way, I use this script in CmakeLists.txt to find arrow:

```
find_package(arrow CONFIG REQUIRED)
if (${arrow_FOUND}) 
    message(STATUS "Found Apache Arrow: ${arrow_FOUND}")
    message(STATUS "Apache Arrow Version: ${ARROW_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS "Apache Arrow DLL Version: ${ARROW_FULL_SO_VERSION}")
endif()
```

And this is the cmake output for this snippet:

```
1> [CMake] -- Found thrift: E:/sandbox/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static
1> [CMake] -- Found Apache Arrow: 1
1> [CMake] -- Apache Arrow Version: 6.0.1
1> [CMake] -- Apache Arrow DLL Version: 600.1.0
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14800) in Apache Arrow fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/apache/arrow/commit/fe9d031936b7d2434d87f07f576046441f704344) from december 2021.

I would assume that it will be included in the next release.

It is caused by the introduction of `std::launder` into the standard library in C++17. So if you compile against an older standard version (if possible), you shouldn't run into this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any easy!! way to install arrow 5.0.0 using vcpkg CLI, because it is not the main stream version anymore, and vcpkg automatically installs 6.0.1? the documentation on this subject is super complicated, at least for me.

Comment: @DariushEivazi I don't know anything about Apache Arrow and I don't use vcpkg. I have just noticed from the error message that it is likely a bug in Apache Arrow, so I searched for it and presented you the info I found.